# Postgres Все внешние связи в таблице на определенный столбец?

Tags: postgresql

Как я могу узнать все связи на определенный столбец запросом?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  t2.relname as out_table,
  a1.attname as out_column
FROM pg_constraint c
  INNER JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.confrelid = t1.oid
  INNER JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.conrelid = t2.oid
  INNER JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON (a1.attnum = ANY(c.conkey)) AND a1.attrelid = c.conrelid
  INNER JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON (a2.attnum = ANY(c.confkey)) AND a2.attrelid = c.confrelid
WHERE c.contype = 'f' AND t1.relname = :table
ORDER BY out_table ASC
```